# Navigating Next and Prev Post By Label In Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, blogger

I wrote a code for navigating next and previous posts which are under the same label.

All the posts in this blog will always be under 1 label only. The blog is for a japanese comic (Manga) hosting, so the chapters will be under the 1 common label which is the title of the comic of the chapters.

The code is :

```
<style>
#button_block_container
{
    text-align:center;
}
#next, #prev
{
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 var pT="<data:post.title/>";
 function recentpostslist(json) {
 var eU=new Array();
 var eT=new Array();
 var current,k=0;
   for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++)
   {
     for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
       if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
         break;
       }
     }
    eU[k] = "'" + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + "'";//bs
    eT[k] = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
    k++;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
    if(eT[i]==pT)
      current=i;
    }
    nb(current,eT,eU,k);
 }
 function nb(c,eT,eU,k)
 {
  var np=c-1;
  var pp=c+1;
  if(c!=0)
  {
    if(np!=0)
    {
      var next="<a href="+eU[np]+"><img src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vbAhPUydPwA/WWuen8w2rsI/AAAAAAAAVP4/rutiJBBKz2kYTclTUKtq6W2vBm8pi6uaACLcBGAs/s1600/if_go-next_118773.png' alt='Next Chapter' title='Next Chapter' height='48' width='48'/></a>";
     document.getElementById("next").innerHTML=next;
    }
    if(pp!=k)
    {
      var prev="<a href="+eU[pp]+"><img src='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-jHxFGDn9aj0/WWueoDAidyI/AAAAAAAAVP8/O_okyJkKiE0j621B2b6d6AmWGDL_7SczACLcBGAs/s1600/if_go-previous_118774.png' alt='Previous Chapter' title='Previous Chapter' height='48' width='48'/></a>";
      document.getElementById("prev").innerHTML=prev;
    }
 }
}
 //]]> 
 </script>
 <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
  <script expr:src='&quot;feeds/posts/summary/-/&quot;+data:label.name+&quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=recentpostslist&amp;max-results=999&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
</b:loop>
```

The logic is perfect. It works when I put a title of some chapter in variable `pT` and I use this as the script call back

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/**LABEL NAME**?max-results=150&alt=json-in-script&callback=recentpostslist"></script>
```

But when I put it in Blogger template I needed to use `expr:src` to make it accept `data:label.name`.

By the way here is the explanation of the variables I used.
`eU` is an array  that has all the URL's of the posts under the given label stored in it.
`eT` is an array  that has all the Titles of the posts under the given label stored in it.
`pT` is used for storing the name of the currently browsing chapter name.
I am using `for` loop :

```
for(var i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
    if(eT[i]==pT)
      current=i;
    }
    nb(current,eT,eU,k);
```

In here, it finds out the array index where the current post is located using comparing all the Post Title's in `eT` array with current `if(eT[i]==pT)`,
stores the found index value in `current` and I send it to a function `nb()` with current index, and both arrays and last stored array index `k`.

`np` stores the index value of next post. Since the posts are arranged in Recentpostlist order I had to do `current-1` and Prev post `pp` as `current+1`.

`if(np!=0)` for finding whether there are no more next posts and `if(pp!=k)` for finding whether there are no previous posts.

Now for the problem part:
When I type the code in Blogger HTML template and save it and go to a post, there are no contents of post shown at all.
Only footer and top header loads.

And found out that the problem is with the callback script :

```
 <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
 <script expr:src='&quot;feeds/posts/summary/-/&quot;+data:label.name+&quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=recentpostslist&amp;max-results=999&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
</b:loop>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because there is no space between the delimiters ( `+` and `&quot;`)

The code should instead be -

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<script expr:src='&quot;feeds/posts/summary/-/&quot; +data:label.name+ &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=recentpostslist&amp;max-results=999&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
</b:loop>
```